# The meaning of "stretch of symbol"

Tags: meaning

**The Lawyer in this interpretation would represent capitalist society–not a stretch of a symbol by any means.**

I am a little bit confused by the second part of the sentence (*not a stretch of a symbol by any means*). What is a *stretch of symbol*? Does the author want to say that the only possible way to interpret The Lawyer is the one that he is a representative of the capitalist society and that the alternative interpretations of The Lawyer do not suite at all?

Comment: Look up "stretch" in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

No, "not a stretch" is litotes for "very plausible".

Answer (score 0):

Check this Collins definition [stretch](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/stretch) sense 19.

Maybe you could otherwise say:

> The Lawyer in this interpretation would represent capitalist society–not **an extension/expansion** of a symbol by any means.

But more context is needed to get the meaning you are looking for.

Comment: I thought it was closer to sense 5.

Comment: @snailboat Hmm... maybe the dash is getting me. The second part written as "... *which is* not a stretch of a symbol by any means." would make *stretch* a noun and closer to sense 19. But I think more context is really necessary to pin this down.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it's definitely a noun in the quote, but I think the meaning corresponds pretty well in this case nonetheless.  Compare "That might be stretching it a bit" with "That might be a bit of a stretch".  In the former we have a verb and the latter a noun, but I think the basic sense of *stretch* is the same in both.